# Kafka Consumer lag configuration with micrometer

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, micrometer

I am trying to configure consumer lag for my Kafka consumers, is there a way to configure this using micrometer. I don't find proper examples to implement.

Comment: What is the connection between micrometer and Kafka consumer?

Comment: I want to emit the micrometer metrics from my program to ELK